# How to create sitemap.xml from docbook source

Tags: gradle, sitemap, docbook

I need to generate sitemap.xml in the standard Google [acceptable format](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) from my docbook source. I'm currently using gradle to power the build process.

Is there an existing tool out there to generate sitemap.xml automatically as part of the build?

Comment: Not sure if there is any tooling. Probably a XSL would do. Also not 100% clear what kind of sitemap content you expect, from DocBook content. Can you add a small example of how the sitemap.xml should look like?

Comment: The sitemap is really not much more than a list of all html files created. The changefreq and priority elements would probably be hardcoded. lastmod might be able to be calculated from the docbook xml file modification dates.

Comment: Ok, yes sounds good. I was thinking more like one html file per DocBook XML. But yes, when all chapters (or something like that) are rendered as separate html documents, it makes sence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Using Ant from Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html) is seams to be possible as there is an [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) Task for [generating a XML Sitemap](http://andrew-jones.com/blog/ant-task-to-generate-an-xml-sitemap/). Read the manual at [GitHub](https://github.com/andrewrjones/ant-task-sitemap), for the usage details.

```
<target name="generate_sitemap" description="generates the sitemap">
    <taskdef classname="uk.co.arjones.ant.task.Sitemap" name="sitemap"></taskdef>
    <sitemap url="http://organisation.org" gzip="yes" lastmod="now" destdir="${BUILD_DIR}">
        <fileset dir="${BUILD_DIR}">
            <include name="**.docbook"></include>
            <include name="**.dbx"></include>
            <exclude name="google*"></exclude>
        </fileset>
    </sitemap>
</target>
```